# Stream TypeORM result (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, typeorm

Has anyone been able to stream the result from typeorm query and pipe it to a write stream ?

this is what I am doing
`inputStream.pipe(jsonexport()).pipe(wStreamCSV)`

inputStream is the ReadStream from typeorm and I am converting this to CSV and writing to wStreamCSV. This all works if I 1st create the JSON file from the query output and then read that.

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of RowDataPacket
```

There is very limited documentation available about the `stream()` function

-Jani

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out

You need to run the read stream thru a transform stream to stringify the returned RowDataPacket object. You can then pipe it to a write stream or pipe it directly to the http response (like I do)

```
const transform = new Transform({
            objectMode: true,
            transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
                this.push(JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, chunk)));
                callback();
            }
        });
```

`inputStream.pipe(transform).pipe(jsonexport())`